# Prevent x from deleting fold in Vim

Tags: vim, folding

I really like the `zx` key combination in Vim (it folds everything but the active area of text).
However, it seems like quite a dangerous key combination.
Pressing `x` on a fold deletes the fold.
Thus, if `z` is omitted, or gets captured by some other preceding key combination, it
becomes quite easy to accidentally delete the text in a fold by pressing `x` on its own.

Given that `dd` can also be used to delete the text in a fold, it would be good if I could
disable `x` as a fold deletion tool.

- How can `x` be disabled as a fold deletion key?

Comment: 1) Why not use undo and forget about it by the way? 2) Try `set foldclose=all` in your vimrc for a while, you may like it. (works best with `foldmethod=marker`)

Comment: @EElvex I do use undo. I almost always detect the accidental fold deletion and press `u`. However, this still seems like a risky strategy in the longer term. Thanks for the `set foldclose=all` suggestion. Although I like to have the control, I might grow to like it.

Comment: With latest vim and the persistent undos, and undobranches, I don't know why you are afraid of a "bad" keystroke !

Comment: @Drasill Vim undo features are awesome, but they assume that you know that you have made a mistake. When you're expanding and moving around folds, the visual clues of deletion are less obvious. In some of the large documents that I edit intermittently, it might be a long time before I realise that the content has been deleted. Of course, this is unlikely to happen. Almost always, I'll catch the delete. But when it comes to losing content, almost always is not good enough for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable `x` on folds only with the following simple `<expr>` mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> x ((foldclosed('.')==-1)?('x'):('zx'))
```

Unlike @Eelvex function, it keeps all `x` functionality and will also remap `x` being run on folds to `zx`.

Comment: Nice touch, the "redirection" to `zx`.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Disable `x`

You can completely disable `x` (or any other key/combination) by:

```
nmap x <nop>
```

(`x`, by the way, is the same as `dl` not `dd`)

A closed fold is always included as a whole when using operators, thus (afaik) it is not possible to disable `x` just for fold deletion.

#### 2. Automatically open the fold

A possible workaround is to have the fold automatically open when you are "on" it, so `x` would delete only one character (as normal):

```
set foldopen=all
```

but this makes it more cumbersome to navigate through the code.

#### 3. Remap `x`

If you don't mind disabling some of `x`'s functionality (eg delete into register), this will also do the job:

```
function Foldx()
  if foldclosed(".") == line(".")
    echo "Watch it!"
  else
    call feedkeys("dl")
    echo "x"
  endif
 endfunction

 nmap x :call Foldx()<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `dl`. I didn't know that.`x` is the same as `dd` when it comes to deleting a fold. I've updated the post now to make this clearer. However, I wouldn't want to disable `x` completely. It's very useful in its normal role as a means of deleting the character under the cursor.

Comment: If you use `<expr>` mapping you don't need to give up any `x` functionality. And even with your function you could use `v:count1` and `v:register` to keep it: `feedkeys('"'.v:register.v:count1.'x', 'n')`. And, of course, **do not use nmap**. `nnoremap` is better as you don't know what topic starter has already remapped.

Comment: @ZyX: Thanks for your comments. I didn't want to include `v:count` and `v:register` to keep things simple. I didn't know about `<expr>` :)